# Using attributes in slim Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, slim-lang

I'm trying to add the `data-toggle="tab"` to my links, but I can't seem to get it to work. This piece of code works:

```
li = link_to pages_catering_path do
        = "Catering"
```

while this one does not? (I get routing error):

```
li = link_to "catering",pages_catering_path
```

Here is my attempt:

```
  nav.navbar-header.col-md-3
     button.navbar-toggle data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse" type="button" 
        span.sr-only Toggle navigation
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
     .collapse.navbar-collapse.nav-justified
      ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked
       li.active data-toggle = "tab"
        = link_to pages_about_path do
        = "Home"
       li = link_to pages_about_path do
        = "About"
       li = link_to pages_catering_path do
        = "Catering"
       li = link_to pages_deli_and_bread_path do 
        = "Deli & Bread"
       li = link_to pages_pastries_path do
        = "Pastries"
       li = link_to pages_pizza_path do 
        = "Pizza"
       li = link_to pages_subs_path do 
        = "Submarines"
```

I used the HTML to slim converter, but it does not utilize the link_to method in rails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
li = link_to 'catering', pages_catering_path, data: { toggle: 'tab' }
```